# Impala queries are not executed in async manner

Tags: python-3.6, tornado, python-asyncio, impyla

Basically, have a small aiohttp app, which receives list of Impala queries and then sends them Impala. However some of the queries may take long time to complete, so decided to do it in async/parallel way. Got one solution with Threads working, but would love to see if it is possible to achieve same speed using asyncio/tornado only.

My code as following:

```
async def run(self, queries):
    # Here I validate queries
    query_list    = await self.build_query_list(split_queries)        # Format: [[queries for connection_1], [queries for connection_2], ...]

    start         = time.time()
    # Assing group of queries to each connection and wait results
    result_queue = deque()
    await multi([self.execute_impala_query(connection.connection, query_list[index], result_queue) for index, connection in enumerate(connection_list)])

    # Close all connections
    [await self.impala_connect_advance_pool.release_connection(connection) for connection in connection_list]

    # Wait for Impala responses
    while len(result_queue) < connect_limit: 
        continue

    # Send results back


async def execute_impala_query(self, impala_connect, queries, queue):
    return await multi([self.impala_response_to_json_response(impala_connect.cursor(), query, queue) for query in queries])

async def impala_response_to_json_response(self, impala_cursor, query, queue):
    self.logger.info('execute query: {}'.format(query))
    print ('execute query: {}'.format(query))

    def get_results():
        impala_cursor.execute(query)
        results = as_pandas(impala_cursor)
        impala_cursor.close()
        self.logger.info('{} completed'.format(query))
        print ('{} completed'.format(query))
        queue.append(results.to_json(orient='records'))

    IOLoop.current().spawn_callback(get_results)
```

What happens is that once its run, I can see 'execute query: query' messages being printed in the stdout and I'd have assumed that they are all being fired and are executing, however, it takes 2(or more) as long as the version with Threads. Am I getting the whole async concept wrong or got some silly mistake somewhere in the methods?

Answer (score 0):

*whole async concept wrong* Yes, just by invoking a function with `spawn_callback` won't make it async: your DB connector should support async IO. And as I can see it is: I'd advise you to take a look at the [execute_async](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/blob/a7e9b58a20d65f948f6b14586d8aaa9a5e5b2678/impala/hiveserver2.py#L312) method. Then you need to write your own waiting function like [Impyla's _wait_to_finish](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla/blob/a7e9b58a20d65f948f6b14586d8aaa9a5e5b2678/impala/hiveserver2.py#L371), but with [tornado.gen.sleep](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.sleep) instead of `time.sleep()`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I knew I need to do something like that, but hoped for the best :) Will give it a try then. Thanks for pointing that out for me :)